# FCM working on localhost but not on production

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, vercel

I utilized FCM to send notifications in my web app. I can send and receive notifications in my localhost, so everything is working perfectly on localhost. However, I can only receive notifications (sent from firebase console, postman, etc.) but not send them on my deployed version in production.

I am using Vercel to host my server and am using Vercel's API routes. I have the same environment variables on both local and in Vercel. On the browser, I am also getting the same responses from the API route (both success 200) when I logged them. The only difference is that notifications do not appear when I send it from the production version. Also, for whatever reason, Vercel is not displaying any server-side logs so I can't even debug.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

My API/send route in the API folder of my Next.js application

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'
import { initAdmin } from '@/db/firebaseAdmin'
import { getMessaging } from 'firebase-admin/messaging';

export async function GET (req: Request, res: Response) {

    // Initialize Firebase Admin
    const app = await initAdmin();

    // get current time
    const currentTime = new Date();

    try {
        const registrationTokens = [
            'f3QNNQiLrpA4n1ayL46sz6:APA91bE-Zy9ypgl6R9nmBKYc_KgrhZs6sD3NqzEG6pLIsaGEQF2wrPSZpO-MWwanAnP0eHUGmCy2PqesD7ZR3IWNO1uumO3-KAvcjMqFWZ3aFpzaoUGa9UKSUtSP3Zgj0LpePuPluf4T', // mobile
            'fWRzguAj87BidFhkNCRdUP:APA91bEfsz8d8XSPW3SOG862V968wvn3vOhu_eJiIG2pGp4a_MrwzUUapzNg8BKvoMuF2FXqFo1f0-YlKjJSqnyf7Y_YfhbTFB8X-PsxcHJ2oOHtUAa-aQHsZg9AK5LcQqOrir9k4X56', // localhost
            'faggSiQojS1TTnljfWE1R7:APA91bHTSLOpEykD75JB_0pyqAautPijFyeLXebor8nVguBHxmvj-eMJzYe6PW51sOoPK4KzAJJlHPc9x-jcFyRurggvXhSFzF8jPtJYfog4RCQSMC1Mi12bRgamCBhSdGz5Rcmhkya9' // deployed desktop
          ];

        const message = {
            notification: {
              title: currentTime.toString(),
              body: "message"
            }
        };

        // Initialize Messaging
        const messaging = getMessaging(app);

        // Send a message to the devices corresponding to the provided registration tokens.
        const sendPromises = registrationTokens.map(token => {
            return messaging.send({ ...message, token: token });
        });

        // Use Promise.all to wait for all messages to be sent
        const responses = await Promise.all(sendPromises);

        console.log('Successfully sent messages:', responses);

        return NextResponse.json({
            message: "Notifications sent",
            responses: responses
        });
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error('An error occurred while sending notifications:', error);
        return NextResponse.json(
            { message: error.message || 'Internal Server Error' },
            { status: 500 }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: try by removing firebase and then again installing it and if did not works then try this (reinstall dependencies )but also deleting the `package-lock.json`